# Does Enterprise Search Center have anything to do with Content Search Results web part?

Tags: enterprise-search, content-search-web-part

I've been wondering what Enterprise Search Center has to do with (if anything) Content Search Results web part and/or Content Search web part. Do I need Enterprise Search Center for the queries to work in Content Search Results web parts?

Answer (score 2):

Their is no relation between Enterprise Search Center & Search Web Parts. Only requirement for the Search Web Parts are, You have to Configure the enterprise Search Services Application.

> Web Parts that use search technology to show content in a publishing
>   environment (referred to in this article as Search Web Parts) show
>   content that was crawled and added to the search index, These Web
>   Parts have queries defined in them, and when users browse to a page
>   that contains a Web Part that uses search technology, the Web Part
>   issues the query automatically. The query result is then displayed in
>   the Web Part. You can modify the query in the search Web Part to fit
>   your content needs.

Please check this for more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679900(v=office.15).aspx

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/search-results-and-content-search-webparts-sharepoint-2013.html